# How to transfer CheckListBox values for an array?

Tags: c++builder

I need get values of an CheckListBox and transfering for an array. When i select the options from CheckListBox in order, for example(01, 02, 03) the results are correct, but if i selecting out of order, for example (04, 05, 06) the array don't get the values and the array values are 0.

My code:

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)    
 {
        CheckListBox1->Items->Add("01");
        CheckListBox1->Items->Add("02");
        CheckListBox1->Items->Add("03");
        CheckListBox1->Items->Add("04");
        CheckListBox1->Items->Add("05");
        CheckListBox1->Items->Add("06");
        CheckListBox1->Items->Add("07");
  }

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    float array[3];
    int optionChecked=0;

    for(int i=0; i<CheckListBox1->Count;i++) {
        if(CheckListBox1->Checked[i] == true) {
            array[i]= StrToFloat(CheckListBox1->Items->Strings[i]);
            optionChecked++;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<optionChecked;i++) {
        ShowMessage(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing `array` using the wrong index. You use `i` but mean to use `optionChecked`. You also run the risk of accessing out of bounds since your array is too short. I would change the code to be like so:

```
float array[7];
int optionChecked=0;

for(int i=0; i<CheckListBox1->Count;i++) {
    if(CheckListBox1->Checked[i] == true) {
        array[optionChecked]= StrToFloat(CheckListBox1->Items->Strings[i]);
        optionChecked++;
    }
}
```

It would be wise to add some defensive code to assert that the length of `array` is equal to `CheckListBox1->Count`.

Comment: Oh, really! Excellent explication. Thanks!